# Dynamic FK using SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, many-to-many

In the `data_id` field of the Product_data table are stored data records id's of bio_data, geo_data **or** phy_data according to the field `dataTable_name` of Product table for a prod_id.

[image]

So, what I need is that, taking into account the name of the table stored in dataTable_name field (bio_data, geo_data or phy_data), the `data_id` field in Product_data will point to that correspondent table records.

How can I define this relationships using sqlAlchemy ORM?

My approach was this:

```
t_Product_data = Table(
    'Product_data', metadata,
    Column('prod_id', ForeignKey(u'Product.prod_id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    Column('data_id', ForeignKey(u'bio_data.bio_id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False),
    schema='public'
)

class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Product'
    __table_args__ = {u'schema': 'public'}

    dataTable_name = Column(String)
    prod_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    data = relationship(u'bio_data', secondary=t_Product_data)
```

This works fine, however, as you can see the declaration is static and works only for the **bio_data** example. 
What I need is to put this to work also for the other data sources (geo_data and phy_data), i don't know, maybe making use of `dataTable_name` field as a variable, like this:

```
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Product'
    __table_args__ = {u'schema': 'public'}

    dataTable_name = Column(String)
    prod_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    data = relationship(dataTable_name, secondary=t_Product_data)
```

And what should I do with the FK data_id in Product_data table? It is possible to create a dynamic FK, that points to different tables according to the value of the field Product.dataTable_name?